# Dojo when drop[dnd drag drop] it creates a new div

Tags: dojo, drag-and-drop

As title, how to make this? I have already done drag and drop using dnd.Source and dnd.Target. Have no idea if it possible to make it when drop and it creates/generates a div which it can closable.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think it would be possible to hook up to the onDndDrop event of your dnd.Target by doing some along these lines:

```
dojo.connect(yourtarget, "onDndDrop", _dndHandler);
```

Then in the _dndHandler function you could create a new div using the dojo.create and dojo.place:

```
var newdiv = dojo.create("div", { innerHTML: "This is my new div" });
dojo.place(newdiv, dojo.byId("your_target_id", "first"));
```

Hope it helps

/Daniel

Comment: Tried with .subscribe instead works like a charm but don't know how to  remove the dragged word left behind...